# Send Outlook Meeting Invitation using Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to send meeting invitations for each row in a worksheet.

I am able to create an item that when displayed shows as an appointment, not a meeting request that can be sent to others. I need to click on "Invite Attendees" in Outlook and then the email addresses display and I can send but it would take a lot of time if I have more than a few rows.

This seems to be a common problem as I found this question in other forums but none have a solution that worked for me.

```vb
Sub SendAction()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Action Log").Range("H5:H50").Cells
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
        If cell.Value Like "*@*" Then      'try with less conditions first
            With OutMail
                .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
                .RequiredAttendees = Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value
                .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value
                .Body = Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value
                .Start = Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & " " & TimeValue("8:00 AM")
                .Location = "Your Office"
                .Duration = 15 ' 15 minute meeting
                .BusyStatus = 0 ' set as free
                .ReminderSet = True 'reminder set
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "20160" 'reminder 2 weeks before
                .display                
            End With

            Cells(cell.Row, "K").Value = "sent"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here is one alternative I tried but it did not fix the issue:

```vb
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)       'waiting for 2 sec to let OL window to display.
SendKeys "%s", True                         'Sending Mail.
Set olApt = Nothing

MsgBox "Invite Sent", vbInformation
```

Source: https://excel-buzz.blogspot.com/2015/03/automation-sending-invitation-to.html

Another alternative is to change `.Display` to `.Save` but the `.Send` function won't work either way and I would then need to open the meeting request from my draft messages in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue. The cell I was linking to for the emails contained a formula instead of the email address text. Once I changed the email addresses to text instead of a formula my VBA worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

Sub SendAction()

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In Worksheets("Action Log").Range("H5:H50").Cells
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
    If cell.Value Like "*@*" Then      'try with less conditions first
        With OutMail
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            .RequiredAttendees = Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value
            .RequiredAttendees.Type = olRequired
            .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value
            .Body = Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value
            .Start = Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & " " & TimeValue("8:00 AM")
            .Location = "Your Office"
            .Duration = 15 ' 15 minute meeting
            .BusyStatus = 0 ' set as free
            .ReminderSet = True 'reminder set
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "20160" 'reminder 2 weeks before
            .display
            .send

        End With

        Cells(cell.Row, "K").Value = "sent"
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! Unfortunately, ".RequiredAttendees.Type = olRequired" returns the runtime error 287: Application-defined or object defined error. Could this be an Office 365 issue?

Comment: Haven't tested your code, but looks like OP is using late binding so should be `1` and not `olRequired`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, I did think of that and it wouldn't work. I tried .RequiredAttendees.Type = 1 and .RequiredAttendees.Type (1) but both resulted in the same error message.

Comment: Thanks BigBen for the clarification! @Sarah good to see you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP but rather than resort to send keys I used the inspector to access the Invite Attendees ribbon command. Here are excerpts from the code:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim oCommandBar As Object 'Office.CommandBars
Dim oInsp As Object 'Outlook.inspector
        
Set outMail = oApp.CreateItem(1)

'then these in the loop to get access to the ribbon:

Set oInsp = OutMail.GetInspector
Set oCommandBar = oInsp.CommandBars

'Show the mail item
outMail.display

'Press the Invite attendees ribbon item
oCommandBar.ExecuteMso ("InviteAttendees")
```