# Limit attendees for an Outlook e-invite

Tags: vba, outlook

I am an amateur coder.

I need to limit an e-invite in Microsoft Outlook to a certain number of attendees.
E.g. I have 500 attendees and I want to limit registration via calendar e-invite acceptance from the 11th attendee onwards ( first come first serve basis for first 10 who signs up).

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking at editing the Outlook VB editor. I suppose it's VB Script solution.

Comment: If you are using the editor, that is VBA. VBScript uses a text file external to any application.

Comment: How do you code this in VBA? That would be of great help! 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580117/send-outlook-meeting-invitation-using-excel

Comment: Thanks braX but I think this doesn't help to solve e issue!

Comment: Sorry to hear that... well... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best what could do is to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

So, you can track how many answers were received and modify the original appointment item to include only ten attendees.