# How to send multiple outlook invites with customized time and attendees?

Tags: excel, outlook

I have multiple outlook meetings to schedule, the details of which are in excel.

Each row has attendees, time and date in different columns. Is there any way to automate sending out meeting invites for each row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580117/send-outlook-meeting-invitation-using-excel

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) in any Microsoft Office application to control Microsoft Outlook. For example, if you are developing a cross-application solution using one primary application and several secondary applications, you can write VBA code in the primary application to automate Outlook to send messages and to store and retrieve information in Outlook items. The [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Getting-Started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) and [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications) articles explain the basics.

```
  Set OutMail = OutApplication.CreateItem(1)  
  With OutMail
      .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
      .RequiredAttendees = Cells(10, "H").Value
      .RequiredAttendees.Type = olRequired
      .Subject = Cells(10, "I").Value
      .Body = Cells(10, "I").Value
      .Start = Cells(10, "E").Value & " " & TimeValue("8:00 AM")
      .Location = "Your Office"
      .Duration = 15 ' 15 minute meeting
      .BusyStatus = 0 ' set as free
      .ReminderSet = True 'reminder set
      .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "20160" 'reminder 2 weeks before      
      .send
   End With
```